# Create in Post Operation Error: Entity Id does not exists CRM 2011 plugin

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I'm facing an issue when trying to create related entities on the post operation of the create step for a entity.

Here is the description of my problem.
There are 3 entities A, B, C in my system where B & C are the related entities(N:1) of A. 
On the Create step, in the Post Operation, for the entity A, trying to create the records for B and C  by assigning the A's ID(guid) for the look-up(relation). This throws me the error saying Entity Id must be specified.....

Weird thing is the ``same plugin, registered in the same way works fine in my QA environment.

Following is the error that is produced.
Unhanded `Exception:System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault, Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]:` Entity Id must be specified for Update Detail:

Really need help on this....
Thanks in advance..

Comment: Have you tried attaching the debugger?

Answer (score 0):

Check what values you have by debugging. Now, attaching a debug in a plug-in isn't sweet but it's a lot better than guessing or creating log files. Does the entity have an id right before you update it?

It could help to show some code as an example.